# Hide Text based on RegistrySearch in WiX Bundle

Tags: wix, burn

Is it possible to use a `RegistrySearch` in WiX bundle to hide a `Text` in theme?
I don't have a clue about where to start. In the code below, the `InstalledDotNet4` variable doesn't set the `Text` in time to disabled and I can't find a way to disable the `Text` (or change its text content).

Bundle.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="My App" Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="ACME"
          UpgradeCode="d88faa97-2197-4154-9e77-32f9ca773bd4">

  <BootstrapperApplicationRef
    Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">

    <Payload SourceFile="Resources/background.png" Id="myLogo" />

  </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

  <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaLicenseUrl" Value="" />
  <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeXml" Value="Resources\MyTheme.xml" />
  <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeWxl" Value="Resources\MyTheme.wxl" />

  <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKCU"
                       Key="Software\AnythingToCheck"
                       Value="Test" Variable="InstalledDotNet4" />

  <Chain>
     <MsiPackage Id="dotNETv4" DisplayName="My .NET v4 prerequisite"
                 SourceFile="myApp.msi" 
                 Visible="yes" 
                 InstallCondition="CheckboxDotNetv4" />
  </Chain>
</Wix>
```

MyTheme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/thmutil/2010">
  <!-- Window definition -->
  <!-- Font definition -->

  <Page Name="Install">
    <Checkbox Name="CheckboxDotNet4"
              X="205" Y="126"
              Width="-100" Height="17"
              TabStop="yes" FontId="3"
              HideWhenDisabled="yes">.NET Framework 4.0</Checkbox>
    <Text Name="InstalledDotNet4"
          X="-10" Y="126"
          Width="80" Height="17"
          TabStop="no" FontId="3"
          HideWhenDisabled="yes">(Installed)</Text>
  </Page>

  <!-- More pages -->
</Theme>
```

Additionally, I tried to use the following code in Bundle.wxs, but that is not linked to the `RegistrySearch`:

```
<Variable Name="InstalledDotNet4State" Type="string" Value="disable" />
```

Comment: I added my own answer, but in a fair and polite way, I will not mark my question as answered for 24 hours, in case someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after extensive research I found it is possible to hide the `Text` based on a `RegistrySearch`. First you need to download the *WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application* from http://wixextba.codeplex.com/. Extract the contents and add to your project the `WixBalExtensionExt.dll` as shown in `Bundle10.wxs` example.

Then, open the project `bafunctions` under folder `Template bafunctions`. You will need to compile this C++ library and add it to your bundle as a `Payload` (use the `Bundle10.wxs` as example).

Then, to be able to read and hide the `Text` control, uncomment function `OnDetectComplete()` and add the following code, for example:

```c
STDMETHODIMP OnDetectComplete()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    LPWSTR sczValue = NULL;

#if DEBUG
    // Show log info during debug.
    // May not be THE way to log.
    size_t i; 
    LPSTR sczValue2 = (char *) malloc(100);
#endif

    BalGetStringVariable(L"InstalledDotNet4Reg", &sczValue);
    BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get variable.");

    if (sczValue == NULL)
    {
        BalLog(BOOTSTRAPPER_LOG_LEVEL_STANDARD,
            "Failed to read null variable.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (_wtoi(sczValue))
        {
            hr = m_pEngine->SetVariableString(L"CheckboxDotNetv4State",
                L"disable");
            BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set control state.");
            hr = m_pEngine->SetVariableNumeric(L"CheckboxDotNetv4", 0);
            BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set variable.");
        }
        else
        {
#if DEBUG
            // Log information
            wcstombs_s(&i, sczValue2, (size_t)100, sczValue, (size_t)100);
            BalLog(BOOTSTRAPPER_LOG_LEVEL_STANDARD, sczValue2);
#endif
            hr = m_pEngine->SetVariableString(L"InstalledDotNet4State",
                L"disable");
            BalExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to set control state.");
            }
        }

LExit:
    ReleaseStr(sczValue);

    return hr;
}
```

Finally, change (or add) your `RegistrySearch`, this way:

```xml
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\FCDAC0A0AD874C333A05DC1548B97920"
    Variable="InstalledDotNet4Reg" Result="exists" />
```

Comment: I don't follow what you did. How does InstalledDotNet4State hide your text?

Comment: @Jippers, if I understand your question correctly, the 'InstallDotNet4State' hides the text because the variable name (without the State) maps to the control 'InstallDotNet4'. Then if I set its value to 'disable', then the control with same root name will be invisible (disabled). For example, you can name your control 'MyControl' and in C++ code set the variable 'MyControlState' to 'disable', so the control will be ultimately disabled.

Comment: Thanks Marlos. I found through the myriad of (un)documentation of how the variable *State is automatically mapped to the * control name.

Comment: tested the solution. It hides the textbox regardless of the outcome of the registry search. The registry key exists or not, the textbox will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. A quick question: are there other magic words we should known about? "disable", "invisible", "greyedout", stuff like that.

Comment: @Alex I don't think there are other magic words. In the source code, folder wixstdba, there is a file named WixStandardBoostrapperApplication.cpp. The 'state' word is used there, in method `OnChangeState`.

Comment: @Marlos I do what you have mentioned and it works for me, so thanks for that. But have a couple of questions regarding it - 1. I have to remove the reference for WixBalExtension in order to add WixBalExtensionExt. Is that ok? 2. Do I have to change anything in the namespace definition since building it, though successful, gives me messages in VS2012 like, Could not find schema information for element WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication and could not find schema information for attribute LicenseFile/LocalizationFile, etc.